# How to get thread start address in Windows?

Tags: windows, thread, processhacker

I'm writing thread finder in module. My goal is find all threads in process and find threads currently working address locations. Like image on below. I do this goal with NtQueryInformationThread API.

[image]

I'm search all web, and I find little bit code pieces. I compile and run my program, but thread start address is always being 0x00000 or 0xccccc. Where I do mistake? My Thread Start Address Finder function is here:

```
#define ThreadQuerySetWin32StartAddress 9

typedef NTSTATUS(WINAPI* NTQUERYINFOMATIONTHREAD)(HANDLE, LONG, PVOID, ULONG, PULONG);
DWORD WINAPI GetThreadStartAddress(__in HANDLE hThread)
{
    NTSTATUS ntStatus;
    DWORD dwThreadStartAddr = 0;
    NTQUERYINFOMATIONTHREAD NtQueryInformationThread;

    if ((NtQueryInformationThread = (NTQUERYINFOMATIONTHREAD)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("ntdll.dll"), "NtQueryInformationThread"))) {
        ntStatus = NtQueryInformationThread(hThread, ThreadQuerySetWin32StartAddress, &dwThreadStartAddr, sizeof(DWORD), NULL);
    }

    return dwThreadStartAddr;
}
```

Comment: Iirc this api is documented include winternl.h  second iirc for this threadinfoclass you need sizeof(pvoid) not sizeof(dword). And check returned bytes , ntstatus etc compile with w4 and /analyze.  Also check dbgeng.h the dbgeng has methods to retrieve this

Answer (score 1):

Like I Commented this function is documented in winternl.h and you can use ntdll.lib to link with
also start address being a pointer will need 8 bytes in x64

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <winternl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    ULONG64 Tinfo = 0;
    ULONG retlen = 0;
    NTSTATUS ntqitret = NtQueryInformationThread(GetCurrentThread(), (THREADINFOCLASS)9,
    &Tinfo, sizeof(PVOID), &retlen);
    printf("START  = %I64x\nret    = %x\nretlen = %x\n",Tinfo, ntqitret, retlen );
}
```

compiling ,executing , comparing

```
:>cl /Zi /W4 /analyze /Od /EHsc /nologo ntqit.cpp /link /release ntdll.lib
ntqit.cpp

:>ntqit.exe
START  = 7ff73b0d1434
ret    = 0
retlen = 8

:>cdb -c "x ntqit!*maincrt*;q" ntqit.exe | awk "/Reading/,/quit:/"
0:000> cdb: Reading initial command 'x ntqit!*maincrt*;q'
00007ff7`3b0d1434 ntqit!mainCRTStartup (void)
quit:
```